# Deploying external wars in Tomcat via IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a project that is dependent on two `war files` being deployed to Tomcat. So every time I want to test it, I need to build an artifact and manually deploy it alongside the two `wars`. Is there a way to somehow add those `war files` to my Idea project so they can be deployed automatically by pressing Shift+F10.

I would deploy it manually, but I have several people working on the project and it would greatly simplify the communication.

Wars are external and they have no sources, so creating new modules/artifacts out of their source is out of the question.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the link on the accepted answer is dead, here is the process, step by step (I'm using Intellij 14):

1) Select `Run/Edit Configuration`

2) If no Tomcat Run Config exists yet, create one

3) Select the Tomcat run config just created, on `Deployment` tab, under `Deploy at server startup` section, click the "+" (right sidebar), select `External source`, and select your war file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add external webapps to deploy at startup at the `Deployment-Tab` of your tomcat runtime configuration page.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-tomcat.html?search=tomcat#d884440e708

Comment: That works, thanks! Do you by any chance know where did the checkbox "Deploy apps already deployed to tomcat" from Idea 12 went?