# Blank browser page when running websphere app in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, websphere

I'm having a frequent problem when attempting to run my java app from the IntelliJ IDE. It was previously developed in RAD Eclipse and was recently "mavenized" from RTC/Jazz. While I can manually do a 'mvn clean install' (in a Terminal window) and get an ear created or start up my local server and auto-startup the email app from the IntelliJ IDE, I just get a blank page displayed in the browser. It's almost like it's not finding the struts-config.xml and/or tiles-def.xml when starting up even though both files are found in the app's war file. I also get the same problem when I deploy the app to our IT environment. I've sporadically gotten it to work by removing the app from my local websphere server before building the artifacts and starting up the server and the app in the IDE but this isn't consistent.

Anyone have any insight on this kind of issue?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274688 could be the case.

Comment: IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1 / build #IU 191.6183.87 built on March 26, 2019. Note: we have another java app that was successfully "mavenized" and runs just fine in the local environment as well as our higher environments.

Comment: Try deploying using the External Source option that is built via Maven instead of using IntelliJ IDEA artifact.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. How do I do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29552241/104891.

Comment: I tried that - removed the ear references in the Deploy at the server startup section and added my war file. Stopped/restarted server and got an error during the startup. Even if I screwed up in this change, I don't see how this setting would affect the app when running this in our higher environments since we aren't using IntelliJ on those websphere servers.

Comment: If the issue occurs with the war/ear built by Maven, it's likely the issue has no relation to the IDE at all and you should remove `intellij-idea` tag from your question.

Comment: Removed tag. I added it to provide complete context of situation.

Comment: If you're still having trouble, can you point to a recreate project perhaps?